# Where to include table headers in dynamically created table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
function createTable(){
  $('#mytable').empty();
  mytable = $('<table></table>');
  var rows = $("#rowcount").val();
  var cols = $("#columncount").val();
  var tr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      $('<td></td>').text(i).appendTo(row);
    }
  }

  $('#box').empty();
  mytable.appendTo("#box");
}
```

```css
table td{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Time:<p id="demo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">Channels View</div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10"> 
                   Row Count:<input type="text" id="rowcount" />
                   Column Count:<input type="text" id="columncount" />
                   <input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" />
                   <div id="box">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is my code. It creates the table dynamically. But if I want to add the header to the table where should I put header fields. And also if I need to display the db values inside the table with respect to the key values how should I do it?

Comment: `var header = true;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
 if(header){
  $('<th></th>').text(i).appendTo(row);
 }else{
      $('<td></td>').text(i).appendTo(row);
 }

}
header = false;
}` i assume your 0th row contains header.

Comment: Yes ,But how to vary it .ie., for each columns how should i give the header values

Answer (score 0):

Table has two sections inside it `thead` and `tbody`

Your head data should go into `thead` and data should go into `tbody`

create a `table` with `thead` and `tbody` as shown below

```
 mytable = $('<table><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
```

then get the `head` and `body` reference from your created table

```
var head = mytable.find('thead tr');
var body = mytable.find('tbody');
```

Now append your headers in `<th></th>` to the `head`

```
for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    $('<th></th>').text('Head-'+j).appendTo(head);
}
```

and append your data in `<td></td>` to the `body`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(body);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      $('<td></td>').text(i).appendTo(row);

    }

}
```

Check out the full snippet

**SNIPPET**

```js
function createTable() {
  $('#mytable').empty();
  mytable = $('<table><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
  
  var head = mytable.find('thead tr');
  var body = mytable.find('tbody');
  
  var rows = $("#rowcount").val();
  var cols = $("#columncount").val();
  var tr = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    $('<th></th>').text('Head-'+j).appendTo(head);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(body);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      $('<td></td>').text(i).appendTo(row);

    }

  }

  $('#box').empty();
  mytable.appendTo("#box");


}
```

```css
table td, th {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table th{
   background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Time:
<p id="demo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              Channels View

            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  Row Count:<input type="text" id="rowcount" /> Column Count:<input type="text" id="columncount" />
                  <input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" />
                  <div id="box">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-1"></div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/sfeecnch/

```js
 createTable = function(){
   $('#mytable').empty();
    
    var rows = $("#rowcount").val();
    var cols = $("#columncount").val();
    
    // -- adding header
    
    var myTable = $('<table></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
    var theadRow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(thead);
    
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      $('<th></th>').text('Col ' + (j+1)).appendTo(theadRow);
    }
    $(thead).appendTo(myTable);
    $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo(myTable);
    
    var tr = [];
   
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(myTable);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
       $('<td></td>').text(i).appendTo(row);
      }
    }

    $('#box').empty();
    myTable.appendTo("#box");
}
```

```css
table td{
 padding:10px;
 margin:10px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Time:<p id="demo">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="box box-info">
<div class="box-header with-border">
Channels View

</div>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10"> 
 Row Count:<input type="text" id="rowcount" />
 Column Count:<input type="text" id="columncount" />
 <input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" />
 <div id="box">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,it solves my request.But how should I change the header values dynamically. ie., I don't need of fixed values **ie.,'Col' here**  instead of it,If I need to get the header values from db how should I

Comment: @nishanthi...Table header is a dynamic one. If you see the Col number is dynamic where as **Col** is a fixed...  What dynamic header you are looking for...

Comment: Yeah right!! But instead of display the "i" values ie.,col-1 ,2,3 how should i display the db field values there

Comment: Where you have the db data ???? Please provide a sample db data, we will definitely help you...

Comment: public function newProduct($value)
     {
      
  $users=addModel::select('Description','technicalSpecification','Features')->where('productName',$value )->get();
   return json_encode($users);
 }-->this is my laravel controller code.How I display those data with header fields

Comment: @nishanthi ... I don't understand Laravel.... You might be doing an AJAX call to get the data... Open the browser network panel & grab the response & paste it in comment section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149874/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-shiladitya).

Comment: No SIR!! I still stuck with that

Comment: I have given some code samples of mine in discussion room SIR!!-->Intimate me if you can't able to view it